# C# WPF MVVM: Не работает привязка TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Хочу привязать к `textbox` строку, у которой есть геттер и сеттер. При попытке привязки с `Mode TwoWay` выдает `A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property`. Свойство не readonly, вообще никак, пробовал даже делать строку полностью публичной, но не работает.

`Model(только эта строка и свойство)`

```
 private string _DataTextBox;

 public string DataTextBox
        { 
            get { return _DataTextBox; } 

            set
            {
                this._DataTextBox = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("DataTextBox");
            } 
        }
```

`VM(только ссылка на это свойство)`

```
public string DataTextBox => _model.DataTextBox;
```

`View(текстбокс, только биндинг)`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataTextBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </TextBox>
```

Не пойму что ему не так.

Comment: `public string DataTextBox => _model.DataTextBox;` и есть ридонли

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Когда вы пишете `=> _model.DataTextBox` - это равноценно `SomePropert {get => _model.DataTextBox }`, то есть просто "Получить значение". Если хотите полностью пробросить, то надо писать руками и `get => _model.DataTextBox` и `set => _model.DataTextBox = value;`.

Comment: INPC надо во вьюмодели реализовывать.